# Vue3 component is not rendering when imported using options API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuejs3-composition-api

So I created a fresh vue3 application and a vue3 module. The application is using the vue3 module as a dependency. In the vue3 module, I am just exporting a component (this component has a child components). In the application, the exported component from the module renders but the child components doesn't render. (getting a vue warning "**resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup().**"). Currently using options API in the module, but when I switched to composition api (using <script setup>), the child components of the module renders with no problem.

I kinda want to stick with options API because currently I am migrating a enterprise module from vue2 to vue3, and  I want to avoid big changes if possible. (All of the components in the module are using options API, and re-writing it to composition API will take a lot of time).

exported component in the module, AppVue3.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test App Vue 3</h1>
    <ModuleHelloWorld msg="Vite + Vue"></ModuleHelloWorld>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ModuleHelloWorld from './components/ModuleHelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ModuleHelloWorld
  },
  created() {
    console.log('App Vue 3 CREATED');
  }
};
</script>
```

ModuleHelloWorld.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ msg + ' hehe' }}</h1>
    <h1>Test Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  components: {
    SecondComponent
  },
  props: ['msg'],
  created() {
    console.log('THIS IS CREATED');
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.read-the-docs {
  color: #888;
}
</style>
```

ModuleHelloWorld.vue is not rendering when options API is used in AppVue3.vue. But when I use <script setup>, ModuleHelloWorld.vue is rendering with no problem:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test App Vue 3</h1>
    <ModuleHelloWorld msg="Vite + Vue"></ModuleHelloWorld>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import ModuleHelloWorld from './components/ModuleHelloWorld.vue'
</script>
```

I'm searching for hours now and can't find any relevant solutions. I will really appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's specific to your setup and vue version and probably other details that aren't shown. Generally you shouldn't be able to reproduce, there's no fundamental problem in doing what you try.

Comment: What was your solution, I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use defineAsyncComponent. Import from vue defineAsyncComponent

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
```

and then:
remove this:

```
import ModuleHelloWorld from './components/ModuleHelloWorld.vue'
components: { ModuleHelloWorld },
```

and add this

```
  components: {
        "ModuleHelloWorld": defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/ModuleHelloWorld.vue')) 
}
```